# Access Smart contract variables without web3

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Are there any APIs available for accessing public Smart Contract variables?
I want to access these variables https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xcf4fef302b96704ad5a6b038ca66597540be1b33#readContract from a github.io page thus I can't install dependencies like web3. I know etherscan has an API but all I've been able to get from that API is the contract ABI. I don't want to set up a separate server specifically for querying for this information.

Comment: I don't understand your issue with using web3.js on the page. You can certainly query a public node like [Infura](https://infura.io) via the JSON-RPC interface over HTTP, but using web3.js is much easier. Did you run into some sort of trouble using web3.js?

Comment: How can I use web3 on github.io? I'm not knowledgeable on how to include web3 in my site

Comment: Download web3.min.js from https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/dist and then just include it in a script tag, like any other JavaScript file.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I could do it like that